# Show notification bar for certain time duration

Tags: javascript, css, jsp

This code will execute when it get curtain time and show notification bar for ten minutes.

I want to use this code in login system.When user login on certain time,it shows notification bar.But i want to see notification bar if user login after certain time but within ten minutes 
for example
 if the login time is two minutes after certain time,it shows notification bar for eight minutes .

is it possible and how?

```js
(function () {
    function checkTime(i) {
        return (i < 10) ? "0" + i : i;
    }

    function startTime() {
        var today = new Date(),
            h = checkTime(today.getHours()),
            m = checkTime(today.getMinutes()),
            s = checkTime(today.getSeconds());
            // ms = checkTime(today.getMilliseconds());
        document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
         t = setTimeout(function () {
            startTime()
        }, 1000);
    
    if(h==16 && m==52 && s==00 )
                {
             alertify.notify('sample', 'success', 60, function(){  console.log('dismissed'); });
                    }
                    else  if(h==17 && m==01 && s==00 )
                {
             alertify.notify('difficult', 'success', 60, function(){  console.log('dismissed'); });
                    }
                
    }
 
        startTime();   
})();
```

```css
<script src="js/alertify.min.js"></script>
<!-- include the style -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/alertify.min.css" />
<!-- include a theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/default.min.css" />
<!-- CSS -->

<!-- CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/alertifyjs/1.4.1/css/alertify.min.css"/>
<!-- Default theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/alertifyjs/1.4.1/css/themes/default.min.css"/>
<!-- Semantic UI theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/alertifyjs/1.4.1/css/themes/semantic.min.css"/>
<!-- Bootstrap theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/alertifyjs/1.4.1/css/themes/bootstrap.min.css"/>

<!-- 
    RTL version
-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/alertifyjs/1.4.1/css/alertify.rtl.min.css"/>
<!-- Default theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/alertifyjs/1.4.1/css/themes/default.rtl.min.css"/>
<!-- Semantic UI theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/alertifyjs/1.4.1/css/themes/semantic.rtl.min.css"/>
<!-- Bootstrap theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/alertifyjs/1.4.1/css/themes/bootstrap.rtl.min.css"/>
```

```html
<div id="time"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

simple math:

10 minutes in second = 600;

```
timeElapsed = currenttime - timeToAlert;
if ((timeElapsed >=0) && (timeElapsed <600)){
//show the alert
timeToShowAlert = 600-timeElapsed;
showAlertForTime(timeToShowAlert);
}
```

Comment: i need more appropriate answer that i can use in my project... thanks Mr. Amir bar